# ldap_bind(): Failed to establish connection to "Online LDAP testserver" from Lumen API

Tags: php, laravel, ldap, lumen

I'm using the latest version of Lumen in my backend API.
I want to connect to an LDAP Server for user authentication from my Middleware. 
The flow from router, to middleware to controller so far works.
I've also successfully enabled LDAP in my XAMPP 7.3.1 (Windows 10, x64).

However, the connection to the LDAP Online demoserver (https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/ ) fails...

Here is the code of the middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Log;
use App\User;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;

class ldapMiddleware {


  public static function testLdap(){

    Log::info("hello ldapMiddleware");
    // check http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

// Active Directory server
$ldap_host = "ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389";

// connect to active directory
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldap_host) or die("Could not connect to LDAP Server");

//user dn
$ldapadmin = "ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com";


// Password
$ldappass = "password";


    Log::info("ldap_connect returned " . $ldapconn);
    ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

  if(ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapadmin, $ldappass)) {
      Log::info("Bind successful!");
    }else{
      Log::info("Invalid user/pass or other errors!");
    }

  }

}
```

It's from a small tutorial and I've also checked on the php documentation for ldap_bind(), and so far the code seems fine in my eyes. But it doesn't work :( 
What am I missing? Do I need to configure Lumen? I couldn't find much info on doing this in Lumen, since most results on google revolve around using libraries for laravel to implement LDAP authentication. But I'm not using laravel so this doesnt help me much ^^

EDIT:
I edited my credentials as suggested to "uid=tesla,ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com"
 but I still get these errors inside my logfiles:

```
 [2019-12-16 08:05:14] local.INFO: hello ldapMiddleware  
[2019-12-16 08:05:14] local.INFO: ldap_connect returned Resource id #162  
[2019-12-16 08:05:16] local.ERROR: ErrorException: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in E:\aether-backend\app\Http\Middleware\ldapMiddleware.php:34
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(2, 'ldap_bind(): Un...', 'E:\\aether-backe...', 34, Array)
#1 E:\aether-backend\app\Http\Middleware\ldapMiddleware.php(34): ldap_bind(Resource id #162, 'uid=tesla,ou=sc...', 'password')
#2 E:\aether-backend\app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php(33): App\Http\Middleware\ldapMiddleware::testLdap()
#3 [internal function]: App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request), NULL)
#4 E:\aether-backend\vendor\illuminate\auth\RequestGuard.php(58): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request), NULL)
#5 E:\aether-backend\vendor\illuminate\auth\GuardHelpers.php(60): Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard->user()
#6 E:\aether-backend\vendor\illuminate\auth\GuardHelpers.php(70): Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard->check()
#7 E:\aether-backend\app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php(38): Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard->guest()
#8 E:\aether-backend\vendor\illuminate\pipeline\Pipeline.php(171): App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate->handle(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request))
#10 E:\aether-backend\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Routing\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request))
#11 E:\aether-backend\vendor\illuminate\pipeline\Pipeline.php(105): Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request))
#12 E:\aether-backend\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(413): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#13 E:\aether-backend\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(259): Laravel\Lumen\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))
#14 E:\aether-backend\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(165): Laravel\Lumen\Application->handleFoundRoute(Array)
#15 E:\aether-backend\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(416): Laravel\Lumen\Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}(Object(Laravel\Lumen\Http\Request))
#16 E:\aether-backend\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(171): Laravel\Lumen\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))
#17 E:\aether-backend\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\src\Concerns\RoutesRequests.php(108): Laravel\Lumen\Application->dispatch(NULL)
#18 E:\aether-backend\public\index.php(28): Laravel\Lumen\Application->run()
#19 {main} {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server at E:\\aether-backend\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\ldapMiddleware.php:34)
[stacktrace]
#0 [internal function]: Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->Laravel\\Lumen\\Concerns\\{closure}(2, 'ldap_bind(): Un...', 'E:\\\\aether-backe...', 34, Array)
#1 E:\\aether-backend\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\ldapMiddleware.php(34): ldap_bind(Resource id #162, 'uid=tesla,ou=sc...', 'password')
#2 E:\\aether-backend\\app\\Providers\\AuthServiceProvider.php(33): App\\Http\\Middleware\\ldapMiddleware::testLdap()
#3 [internal function]: App\\Providers\\AuthServiceProvider->App\\Providers\\{closure}(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\Request), NULL)
#4 E:\\aether-backend\\vendor\\illuminate\\auth\\RequestGuard.php(58): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\Request), NULL)
#5 E:\\aether-backend\\vendor\\illuminate\\auth\\GuardHelpers.php(60): Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard->user()
#6 E:\\aether-backend\\vendor\\illuminate\\auth\\GuardHelpers.php(70): Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard->check()
#7 E:\\aether-backend\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\Authenticate.php(38): Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard->guest()
#8 E:\\aether-backend\\vendor\\illuminate\\pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): App\\Http\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\Request))
#10 E:\\aether-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\Request))
#11 E:\\aether-backend\\vendor\\illuminate\\pipeline\\Pipeline.php(105): Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\Pipeline->Laravel\\Lumen\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\Request))
#12 E:\\aether-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(413): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#13 E:\\aether-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(259): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))
#14 E:\\aether-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(165): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->handleFoundRoute(Array)
#15 E:\\aether-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(416): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->Laravel\\Lumen\\Concerns\\{closure}(Object(Laravel\\Lumen\\Http\\Request))
#16 E:\\aether-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(171): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->sendThroughPipeline(Array, Object(Closure))
#17 E:\\aether-backend\\vendor\\laravel\\lumen-framework\\src\\Concerns\\RoutesRequests.php(108): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->dispatch(NULL)
#18 E:\\aether-backend\\public\\index.php(28): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->run()
#19 {main}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the connection is working with a different tool? Like e.g. with Apache Directory Studio? Or the CLI?

Comment: @heiglandreas I can't use ldapsearch from cmd, it doesnt know the command. Concerning Apache Directory Studio I cant get it to run :/ I tried out different tools such as "LDAP Admin" but the connection fails. Could you tell me if the forumsys server is still available/online? I currently dont know if its my mistake or not that nothing worx xD

Comment: That was my idea. The post is from 2014 and I'm not sure the server is still online. So perhaps you are chasing some errors that are not based on your side. But it looks like it's still online. Then it's the question whether you can have access to it from your network. Perhaps the port is blocked in the firewall.... You can try `telnet ldap.forumsys.com 389` from your machines CLI to see whether you can connect to the server

Comment: @heiglandreas Got the problem, our internal firewalls were blocking the port from making requests leaving our network :/

Comment: Great to know that you found the issue 

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the rdn of one of the proposed users.

> You may also bind to individual Users (uid) or the two Groups (ou) that include:
>
> `ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com`
>
> - riemann
> - gauss
> - euler
> - euclid
>
> `ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com`
>
> - einstein
> - newton
> - galieleo
> - tesla

For example, if you want to bind as Leonhard Euler, your bind dn is :

```
uid=euler,ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com
```

To bind as Nikola Tesla :

```
uid=tesla,ou=scientists,dc=example,dc=com
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I did as you suggested but it didnt really change much, see my edit to my question above :(